# Android memory categories "Graphics" and "Others" don't get garbage collected

Tags: android, picasso, android-profiler

[image: RAM Profiler]

The memory consumtion rises indefinetly and I doubt that a memory consumtion of nearly 1GB is normal. My app is a very image-heavy app that uses Picasso as the image library. But even with the `.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)` modifier, the memory footprint stays roughly the same. Another issue that is visible on this image is the "Others" category that never gets garbage collected.

Is there a way to lower the memory usage of the "Graphics" or the "Others" category?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior bc garbage collection only applies to Java memory (memory controlled by the JVM). Also note that the Android Studio Profiler is a purely a visualization tool--it shows the breakdown of memory usage, but minimizing such usage is up to the developer.

Comment: this is helpful information - but does not solve the issue. Maybe you have another hint?